# Javascript function Object.keys not working correct

Tags: javascript, object

Javascript function Object.keys seems to not work correct:

```
public availableParents: any[] = [];

availableParents[abbreviation] = textField;
```

the field availableParents is sent to a function.

Then in debug mode I dispay the variable ... and also an Object.keys on the variable :

Immediate window :

```
?dataSource
[]
    __proto__: []
    ALG: "ALG | Alg"
    length: 0
    SC-1-1: "Scene"

? Object.keys(dataSource)
[SC-1-1,ALG]
    __proto__: []
    length: 2
    [0]: "SC-1-1"
    [1]: "ALG"
```

I would have expected that Object.keys would return (?) :

```
[ALG,SC-1-1]
    __proto__: []
    length: 2
    [0]: "ALG"
    [1]: "SC-1-1"
```

Comment: It does not look it is the syntax of javascript, what are you working on ?

Comment: `availableParents = empty list`... I've never felt so sad reading code...

Comment: It's not clear to me what the issue is here.

Comment: Generally when you start thinking "hmm this widely-deployed programming language has a bug", you need to take a step back and re-think.

Comment: it's typescript.

Comment: the issue is that I need them in the order that they were added

Answer (score 1):

You can't order an object. The keys are stocked in (pseudo-)random order.

If you want to keep track of which key/value you put in first, you better have to use arrays.

If you just want to have an alphabetical order, use [`sort()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp) method on your `Object.keys` resulting list

Good luck